# Simplifying a complex fraction

Tags: complex-numbers, fractions

Simplify the complex number: $\frac{(\sqrt{3} + 9i)^{181}}{(-12 + 48\sqrt{3}i)^{90}}$

I've tried a few things such as turning the top and bottom of the fraction into their trigonometric form or trying to factor out a power of 90 on the top and then simplifying from there. The problem is nothing is working for me and I can't see what the trick is. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Here's what I did:
$\dots = \frac{(-72 + 18\sqrt{3}i)^{90} (\sqrt{3} + 9i)}{12^{90} (-1 + 4\sqrt{3}i)^{90}} = (\frac{3}{2})^{90} (\frac{-4 + \sqrt{3}i}{-1 + 4\sqrt{3}i})^{90} (\sqrt{3} + 9i) = (\frac{3}{2})^{90} (\frac{16 + 15\sqrt{3}i}{49})^{90} (\sqrt{3} + 9i)$

I don't know what to do after this.

EDIT 2:
One thing I noticed is that if we set $z = \sqrt{3} + 9i$ and $w = -12 + 48\sqrt{3}i$, then $|z| = \sqrt{84} \implies |z^2| = |z|^2 = 84$ and $|w| = 84$. Therefore the two numbers lay on the same circle with radius $84$. This could potentially be important but I'm not sure.

Comment: It sounds like you used $z^{181}/w^{90}=(z^2/w)^{90}z$ together with polar form, but got stuck. Please edit in your calculations.

Comment: @J.G. I've added what I've done so far.

Comment: Thank you. I wouldn't advise taking out real factors as you did. (You've also made an error in doing so: it should have been $(18^2/12)^{90}=27^{90}$, not $(18/12)^{90}=(3/2)^{90}$.) But if you compute $z^2/w$ in polar form with $z=\sqrt{3}+9i,\,w=-12+48\sqrt{3}i$, you should have more luck.

Comment: Simplify is a very subjective term, here I cannot see anything more than taking the complex number in the denominator out of division and probably taking out real factors because using euler form does not help here as the angles (in radians) are not (in hindsight) some "good $\pi$ containing numbers" that when multiplied by 90 or 181 would produce something good

Comment: @HamLemon the answer, accoring to WolframAlpha, is $\sqrt{3} + 9i$.

Comment: I am pretty sure the answer cannot be what you just stated, are you sure you have entered the correct values into wolfram alpha?

Comment: @HamLemon No, it's okay. I am really confused as to how to simplify the expression is all.

Comment: @HamLemon This is what I input into it: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28sqrt%283%29+%2B+9+i%29%5E181%2F%28-12+%2B+48+sqrt%283%29+i%29%5E90

Comment: Maple agrees, the answer is $\sqrt{3}+9i$.

Comment: @GEdgar does maple show you simplification steps?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, turns out I don't know how to divide

Comment: Yeah it turns out I just made a multiplication error each time I attempted to solve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute by hand, note that $$\frac{(\sqrt{3} + 9i)^{2}}{(-12 + 48\sqrt{3}i)}=\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}=e^{i\pi/3}$$ so the $90$th power is easy.  All that remains is the last factor of $(\sqrt{3} + 9i)$.

Comment: How exactly do we note that? It doesn't seem obvious to me at all

Comment: NEVERMIND I cannot divide numbers...